# Multiple reference to multiple footnote

Tags: footnotes

In my thesis I would like to create references to several footnotes as in this example:

```
....
text1.... text2.......text3
....text2.....text3
......

----------
1 reference1
2 reference2
3 reference3
```

My text is in a table and I want to do it for more notes. How can I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Look at `threeparttable`, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226122/threeparttable-notes-with-1-5-spacing-want-single-spacing